# Find an integer $k$ such that $\cos(x)=x$ in the interval $\left(\frac{k}{10^6}, \frac{k+1}{10^6}\right)$

Tags: calculus, roots

I'm currently struggling on how I should get started with this question. So far I have sketched a graph, but still cannot see what I can do. Can anyone provide some help for me please?

Comment: You surely mean that there exists an $x$ in that Intervall satisfying $\cos(x) = x$, right?

Comment: Solving $\cos(x) = x$ can be reformulated as finding the roots of $f(x) := \cos(x) - x$. What methods do you know for finding roots?

Comment: It say this is equivalent to finding a $k$ such that $$\cos (k/10^6) - k/10^6 < 0 < \cos ((k+1)/10^6) - (k+1)/10^6$$ holds but sadly, WolframAlpha say this inequality has [no solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+cos+%28k%2F10%5E6%29+-+k%2F10%5E6+%3C+0+%3C+cos+%28%28k%2B1%29%2F10%5E6%29+-+%28k%2B1%29%2F10%5E6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is just one point of the plane in which $\cos(x)=x$, take first the solution of this trascendental equation. We have $x_0\approx0.739085$.

Now we need $0.739085\in[\frac{k}{10^6},\frac{k+1}{10^6}]$ so $k\le739085\le k+1$.

Because of the approximation of $x_0$ we can just get an approximated solution. Taking, for example $k=739085$ we get the two following points:
$$(0,739085,0.739085229),\quad (0.739086,0.739084549)$$
These two points are very close in the plane.If you have chosen a finer approximation for $x_0$, the answer given would have varied slightly.By continuity of the function cosinus this approximation is valid since we have
$$\cos(0.739085)\gt0.739085 \text{ and } \cos(0.739086)\lt0.739085$$ in which the solution of the equation above has been assumed to be $x_0=0.739085$